# Why hasn't the industry standardized sink/source according to sensor/plc component type?

Tags: transistors, current-source, plc, current-sink

I know quite enough to understand how sink/source works when connecting sensors and PLCs, as well as how it works concerning the electronics components and circuit diagrams. What I don't understand is why the manufacturers have the freedom to choose beetween sink/source when producing a sensor or PLC.

Wouldn't it be easier if all the sensors were standardized as sink and all the PLCs  as source, the other way around could work as well.

I am probably missing something regarding this claim so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me understand this matter.

Comment: Probably the same reason we don't all speak the same language and or use the same system of measurement even though it would make things more convenient and easier.

Comment: often the mechanical engineering, the packaging, is more creative than the circuit design.

Comment: 99 sensor interface standards on the wall, 99 sensor interface standards on the wall. Take one down, change it around, 100 sensor interface standards on the wall.

Comment: This: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: This would be more answerable if the question focused on a specific example, such as “why must model xxx PT100 RTD sensor module send to PLC by current sink instead of current source?” Or maybe “how can I convert a PLC current-sinking sensor module to a current source or voltage output?”  Otherwise it seems too vague. I get that you’re asking about the systemic problem of inconsistencies between various sensors, but you’re literally asking whether it would be easier if there was only one comprehensive standard — yes, obviously, but that answer isn’t useful by itself. More detail helps.